# Validate either shipping or billing form field if not filled

Tags: magento-1, shipping-address, billing-address, onestepcheckout

Is it possible to validate only either shipping or billing specfic field by javascript.

eg.if billing has email field filled so it should be remove required from shipping and let it go for place order.

[Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/TYXvO76F)

I have tried below code and work but it seems very dirty and long way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* For custom validate extra email and telephone */
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  var billingselectElement = $('billing-address-select');
    if (billingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:extra_email').getValue() == '')  {
        $('billing:extra_email').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('billing:extra_email').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('billing-address-select').observe('change', function(event) {
   var billingselectElement = $('billing-address-select');
    if (billingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:extra_email').getValue() == '')  {
        $('billing:extra_email').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('billing:extra_email').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('billing:extra_email').observe('change', function(event) {
   var billingselectElement = $('billing-address-select');
    if (billingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:extra_email').getValue() == '')  {
        $('billing:extra_email').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('billing:extra_email').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('advice-required-entry-billing:extra_email').hide();

    }
});
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
var isShippingEnable = $('shipping:different_shipping').getValue();
  var shippingselectElement = $('shipping-address-select');
    if (isShippingEnable && shippingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:extra_email').getValue() == '' && $('shipping:extra_email').getValue() == '')  {
        $('shipping:extra_email').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('shipping:extra_email').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('shipping-address-select').observe('change', function(event) {
    var isShippingEnable = $('shipping:different_shipping').getValue();
   var shippingselectElement = $('shipping-address-select');
    if (isShippingEnable && shippingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:extra_email').getValue() == '' && $('shipping:extra_email').getValue() == '')  {
        $('shipping:extra_email').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('shipping:extra_email').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('shipping:extra_email').observe('change', function(event) {
    var isShippingEnable = $('shipping:different_shipping').getValue();
   var shippingselectElement = $('shipping-address-select');
    if (isShippingEnable && shippingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:extra_email').getValue() == '' && $('shipping:extra_email').getValue() == '')  {
        $('shipping:extra_email').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('shipping:extra_email').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('advice-required-entry-shipping:extra_email').hide();

    }
});

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  var billingselectElement = $('billing-address-select');
    if (billingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:telephone').getValue() == '')  {
        $('billing:telephone').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('billing:telephone').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('billing-address-select').observe('change', function(event) {
   var billingselectElement = $('billing-address-select');
    if (billingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:telephone').getValue() == '')  {
        $('billing:telephone').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('billing:telephone').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('billing:telephone').observe('change', function(event) {
   var billingselectElement = $('billing-address-select');
    if (billingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:telephone').getValue() == '')  {
        $('billing:telephone').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('billing:telephone').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('advice-required-entry-billing:telephone').hide();

    }
});
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
var isShippingEnable = $('shipping:different_shipping').getValue();
  var shippingselectElement = $('shipping-address-select');
    if (isShippingEnable && shippingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:telephone').getValue() == '' && $('shipping:telephone').getValue() == '')  {
        $('shipping:telephone').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('shipping:telephone').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('shipping-address-select').observe('change', function(event) {
    var isShippingEnable = $('shipping:different_shipping').getValue();
   var shippingselectElement = $('shipping-address-select');
    if (isShippingEnable && shippingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:telephone').getValue() == '' && $('shipping:telephone').getValue() == '')  {
        $('shipping:telephone').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('shipping:telephone').removeClassName('required-entry');
    }
});
$('shipping:telephone').observe('change', function(event) {
    var isShippingEnable = $('shipping:different_shipping').getValue();
   var shippingselectElement = $('shipping-address-select');
    if (isShippingEnable && shippingselectElement.getValue() == '' && $('billing:telephone').getValue() == '' && $('shipping:telephone').getValue() == '')  {
        $('shipping:telephone').addClassName('required-entry');
    }else{
        $('shipping:telephone').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('advice-required-entry-shipping:telephone').hide();

    }
});
/* End validation */
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery instead simple JS mark first element required (no need if by default) and just depend second one on first: I had created fiddler for your understandings same as your requirements:

[Dependent Required](http://jsfiddle.net/L59b1n7u/73/)

Comment: magento form validation is already doing its work.can't we do it using magento native form validation?

Comment: No magento by default is not doing like that. Jquery definitely added in your project you just need to add little code for this. Let me know if you have any issue in it ?

Comment: id is like `billing:extra_email` can't accept this in jquery

Comment: No need billing:extra_email to accept this. you just have to replace two field ids.